# How to connect piping underneath a kitchen’s double sink?

Tags: plumbing

When I purchased my house, the piping underneath my kitchen sinks looks like this.

[image]

I've been told that they should not be double trapped. Instead, they should look something like this

[image]

So I went to a big-box store got a pipe extension and removed the unnecessary p-trap on the left.
But I ran into a problem aligning the four holes. Is cutting my purchased pipe the only way to have them aligned? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the extension tube is intended to be cut to length so that the top of the tee can align with the strainer basket's outlet.

Before cutting the extension to length, address the problem of the food waste disposer outlet not facing directly toward the tee fitting by rotating the disposer.

In the photo below I've circled a loop in the disposer's mounting hardware. There should be one or maybe two other loops like this on the opposite side of that same metal part (hidden from the camera's view). This part is a ring which clamps the disposer to the sink bracket. You may want help because disposers can be heavy. Support the disposer so it won't fall. Rotate that ring counter-clockwise, wiggle the disposer to break the bond of its gasket to the sink bracket, and rotate it until the outlet-to-tee alignment is correct. Lift it up firmly and re-tighten the ring. You may need a few taps of a hammer or mallet to get the ring loosened.

[image]